# Se han dejado de mostrar los widgets interactive (Jupiter Notebook)

Tags: windows10, jupyter, pip, anaconda3

Mi situación es la siguiente, estoy realizando el trabajo de fin de grado con  Jupyter notebook y de un día para otro los widget interactive han dejado de mostrar los campos de input y solo muestran el return.

[image: IMAGEN DE LA CELDA EN CUESTIÓN]

Para poneros en contexto no tengo mucha idea ni de python ni de jupyter notebook, así que mi troubleshooting se ha limitado a reinstalar el programa. Ahora tampoco me funcionan los comandos PIP desde el cuaderno (si desde la consola de jupyter).

[image: IMAGEN ERROR PIP]

He probado en un entorno virtual (mybinder) y se muestran perfectamente. Estoy apunto de resetear el pc por que la verdad no se que mas hacer y las soluciones online no se adaptan a mi problema. Gracias y un saludo.

P.S. No se que podáis requerir para saber mas, pero comentádmelo y os lo subo sin problemas.

EDIT: He ejecutado los comandos /scannow y /Restorehealth para descartar problemas del sistema operativo. El problema persiste.

EDIT2: He reinstalado Windows 10 tras formatear el ordenador y funciona perfectamente, parece ser que era un problema de Windows y no de jupyter notebook o de anaconda3.

Comment: Si has hallado la respuesta a tu propio problema, puedes publicar tu propia respuesta y marcarla como aceptada ;) Así, todos podremos ver lo que te ayudó en un futuro.